# Список из несколько View одного типа

Tags: java, android, list, view

Можно ли в список загнать несколько View одного типа?

Например, вот так:

```
private List<EditText> editTexts;
editTexts.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ask1));
```

Comment: Если тип одинаковый, то почему нет? Только для начала перед добавлением инициализируйте editTexts к примеру вот так `editTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>()`

Answer (score 1):

Да, и такое иногда можно встретить, особенно когда разметка содержит большое кол-во элементов одного типа. В вашем случае это `EditText`. Я встречал с `ImageView`.

Для того чтобы ответ был более полным, небольшой пример:

```
List<EditText> edList = new ArrayList<>();
int[] edIds = { R.id.ed_1, R.id.ed_2, R.id.ed_3, R.id.ed_4 ... R.id.ed_100 };

for (int i = 0; i < edIds.length; i++)
    edList.add((EditText) findViewById(edList[i]));
```

У данного подхода есть свои минусы не только в поддержке кода, но сделать так можно.